# How to pass a filename/path to text parser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, streamreader

I'm trying to get a simple text parser class to work in VS2015.  I received the class code and built a basic Console Application, added the class `Cawk` and tried to compile/run it.

The main error that I get is

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.StreamReader'

It's clear that I can't figure out how to pass a filename through `Main` to `Cawk`.  How do I give it an argument of a filename?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

My Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
        {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
            Cawk.Execute(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of My Cawk.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public static class Cawk
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> Execute(StreamReader input)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        string line;
        //string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        //read all rows
        while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
```

Answer (score 2):

`Execute` accepts a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) not a string.

```
Cawk.Execute(new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))
```

However, you should close the stream after you are done with it.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))
{
    Cawk.Execute(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
Cawk.Execute(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `File` class from the `System.IO` namespace.

```
Cawk.Execute(File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
string input = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Cawk.Execute(new System.IO.StreamReader(input));
```

You can put using System.IO; to the top like the rest of the usings, then you don't have to write it out later.